# Artifact androidx.work:work-runtime（2.8.0-2.9.0） SystemForegroundService is not adapted to android14

Tags: android-workmanager

When I call `setExpedited()` according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started/define-work#expedited) to declare that a `WorkRequest` should run as quickly as possible using an expedited job, the documentation requires expediting Any `ListenableWorker` that the job runs must implement the `getForegroundInfo` method. I'm using a `CoroutineWorker` and the documentation requires me to pass the `ForegroundInfo` to `setForeground()` within `doWork()`.

At this point, the problem comes if I specify froegroundServiceType in `ForegroundInfo`, the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foregroundServiceType 0x00000001 is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000000 in service element of manifest file` will be thrown; if I do not specify froegroundServiceType, `android.app.InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS with type none callerApp=ProcessRecord{7014511 11425:com.tuya.smartlife/u0a282} targetSDK=34` has been thrown on my app.

Now `SystemForegroundService` is declared in the manifest file in the work-runtime component. Do I need to redeclare `SystemForegroundService` and specify foregroundServiceType in my application to merge in the last manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to redeclare SystemForegroundService and specify foregroundServiceType in my application to merge in the last manifest file?

Doing so helped in my case, although I was not able to find that I should do it in the documentation.

```xml
<service
  android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
  android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
  tools:node="merge" />
```

Note that `foregroundServiceType` might be different in your case. I'm also not sure what to do if the work manager is used for multiple purposes, maybe then `specialUse` fits the best.

Comment: If your service is designed for multiple purposes, multiple types can be combined inside `foregroundServiceType`

Answer (score 0):

if not declare manifast file service type you getting below mention following error

Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 15987
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foregroundServiceType 0x00000001 is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000040 in service element of manifest file
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3015)
https://medium.com/@rmvivek55/android-14-workmanger-foreground-service-type-9cd3b842dd0b